# Check if a file name already exists and make the following logic to work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my code, the user enters a name for an output file. I check if this file name is already existing, if yes, ask the user if overwrite or not. Here follows my code:

```
var outputs_array = new Array();
[..]
var output_form = document.getElementById(form_id);

output_form.onsubmit = function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var output_file = output_form.querySelector("[name="+output.name+"]").value;
 let [usr_filename, usrfileExtension] = output_file.split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
 var format_in = "txt";
 // build up the url to retrieve only files with given format
 var file_list_format_in =  serverURI + "/resources?formats=" + format_in + "";
 var isFileNameOk = 0;
 $.getJSON(file_list_format_in, function(data){
    $.each(data.resources, function(j, resource){
       let [res_filename, resfileExtension] = resource.name.split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
       if(usr_filename == res_filename){
         if(confirm("A file with that name already exists. Overwrite?")){
           isFileNameOk = 1;
           console.log("OVERWRITE " + outputs_array);
          } else {
           console.log("NOT OVERWRITE ");
          }
        } else {
          isFileNameOk = 1;
          console.log("NOT exists ");
        }
     }); // each resource
     if (isFileNameOk) {
        outputs_array.push(output_file);
     }
 }); // resource file list JSON
 console.log("OUTPUT outputs_array " + outputs_array);
} // onsubmit form
```

My goal is to fill the output_array with the names of given output files. The desired behaviour is as follow:

- on form submit, get the list of existing file (`file_list_format_in`),
- loop over each existing file and check if anyone has the same name as the user `usr_filename`
- if YES, then a pop-up dialog asks the user if overwrite or not.
  -> if YES, then set the `isFileNameExisting` to 1
- if NO, do not change `isFileNameExisting` (remains 0)
- Finally, if the `usr_filename` does not exists then push the output_file to the `outputs_array`
  My code does not work, if I enter an existing file name and say yes to overwrite, the `output_file` is not pushed to `outputs_array`. I'm getting crazy to make my logic work as expected.

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: does this `console.log("NOT exists ");` show in console ?

Comment: @Swati yes, it does..

Comment: The problem is that you are outputting `outputs_array` immediately, while your ajax requests are asynchronous, and so the `outputs_array` will be populated later. It is a common problem, and the linked Q&A has all the info on it.

Comment: @trincot: okay, thank you. Right now I can't check the link you shared but sounds like explaining my issue.